# Question about a noun "bolt" in Minecraft

Tags: meaning

I've heard a song about game called Minecraft made by CaptainSparklez that is called "revenge". There is a chorus:

> 'Cause, baby, tonight
> The creeper's tryna steal all our stuff again
> 'Cause, baby, tonight
> You grab your pick, shovel, and **bolt** again (**Bolt** again-gain)
> And run, run until it's done, done
> Until the sun comes up in the morn'
> 'Cause, baby, tonight
> The creeper's tryna steal all our stuff again (Stuff again-gain)

I do not know what *bolt* means in this song. Maybe I don't know some extra definitions of this word. Just, every definition that I've seen have nothing to do with Minecraft.

Comment: Bolt - verb - to run away very fast, in order to escape.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Downvoted because the ratio of dictionary time to Minecraft time is sub-par.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Micheal is correct. By watching the music video, we can see that the word "bolt" accompanies the character running. The next lyrics are "run, run, run" so it is a verb, meaning "to run away very fast, in order to escape" as Micheal put it.

Bolts do not exist within Minecraft, except as lightning bolts, and perhaps in some mods.